# Is the set of all limit points of a continious function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ connected?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness, connectedness

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$A=\{y \in \mathbb{R} : y= lim f(x_n),\textrm{for some sequence } x_n \rightarrow \infty \}$
Then the set of A is necessarily  
A. A connected set 
B. A compact set 
C. A singleton set 
D. None of the above.

What I thought is if the domain is disconnected then A will be disconnected. Moreover, A contains all the limit point and A is a proper subset of R so A will be bounded so it will be compact. But I don't know if I am correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) is true. Let $t,s \in A$ and $t<w<s$. Let $f(x_n) \to t$ and $f(y_n) \to s$. Then, for $n$ sufficienltly large, we get $f(x_n) <w$ and $f(y_n) >w$. So there exists $z_n$ between $x_n$ and $y_n$ with $f(z_n)=w$. Then $z_n \to \infty$  so $w \in A$.

$f(x)=x\sin x$ gives an example where B) and C) are both false.